# QT: how to open a new window

Tags: qt, window

Well, I tried a lot. 
For example,

```
#include "secdialog.h"

buttton ::on clicked()
{
   secdialog  secdialog;
   secdialog.setmodal(true);
   secdialog.exec();
}
```

Well, secdialog does not exist!
Those posts are old at least 5 years.
So, I think some headers are changed or I missed something to add.
Hopefully, I'll find someone to help me.
Easy example where to add headers and where to write...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "QDialog"

buttton::onClicked()
{
   QDialog d;
   d.exec();
}
```

Please also consult the documentation of [QDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qdialog.html). It may also be interesting to go through some [basic examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html).